# Entity Framework DbSet<?> - Column names of database unknown at compile time

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

So I have run into a situation where I need to use the Entity Framework (DbContext) with databases whose columns are not known at compile time.  Basically I don't have the luxury of hard coding a customTable class to put into the DbSet.

The only thing I can think of for solving this issue is using Reflection.Emit to create a customTable class at run-time based on information I glean by interrogating a database.

I was not able to find any information of solving this issue, but I am very new to working with the Entity Framework so maybe a solution would be more obvious to someone more experienced.

I feel like there should be a cleaner way than using Reflection.Emit to dynamically create a class to feed DbSet.

If I am way off base for the intended use of the Entity Framework that information would be useful as well.

Comment: have you tried hard-coding the name of an interface and then use dependency injection to select the desired class at runtime (which offcourse implements the interface)?

Comment: So I did some research into dependency injection.  From what I understand you are suggesting that I code up several classes that implement a common interface and then choose from those classes at run-time via dependency injection.  The issue is that it isn't just a few databases that I could be encountering.  It is any database from any user; so it's not something I can hard-code for in any shape or form.  If I misunderstood let me know, as I had not heard of dependency injection before now.  Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Correct, but that too is possible w/ DI if you need the ability to choose between storing in a SQL database or generate XML files. You could have an interface called IMyClassRepository, then write a SQLMyClassRepo and XMLMyClassRepo class to handle serializing in different ways. And when a third user comes along and demands TXT files, you add a TXTMyClassRepository class... Ninject is a popular DI for .NET; http://www.ninject.org/

Comment: Ah, I worded my response poorly I'm sorry.  I was saying databases, but what I really meant was tables.  The only databases I have to worry about are sql express and sql local db.  My problem is that my program needs to query a known table that could contain an unknown variety of columns at run-time.  I realize now my wording was terrible, sorry about that.

Comment: aah ok. interesting problem. could the user perhaps generate their db schema which the application then can import. not usre if it's even possible. just throwing out ideas here... =). happy coding!

Comment: After a lot of research and trying some strange things like creating a class at run-time via Reflection.Emit to use inside of DbSet I have realized that EF is simply not meant to work in this way.  The things it does with the model make this next to impossible.  I don't understand how such a simple concept as a table with unknown columns can be such a huge hurdle.  I have come to realize that other people have run into this same problem in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308853/changing-ef-model-and-creating-new-entities-in-runtime so this one should probably be closed.

Comment: nice research. good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm investigating this problem too and I have found what seems like the solution.

http://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/

tells you how to make a DbContext into which you add a new DbSet using a type as a parameter.  You can create this type using the Dynamic Linq Library:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

It has a method called CreateClass which will allow you to dynamically build a POCO class definition from a list of field names and load it, you can then create a DbSet using the new type you have created.

You can then get a non-generic DbSet from your updated DbContext using

```
db.Set(type)
```

where 'type' is a variable holding your new type.  This can be worked on using the linq predicates in the dynamic linq library.

Incidentally, my application is for a CMS where new modules can add fields to the core data table for the CMS, and I don't want to use DI as its too inflexible as no given module will be able to provide a type which has all the fields it needs and all the other unknown modules might also need.

James

Comment: If you can make it work in that way my hat is off to you.  I found that in subsequent runs the model created by the EF (Even when using code first) was extremely unhappy with any changes being made to it.  In the end I figured out a way to avoid using EF for my use-case since this is so far from what is intended.